# Why does Clrver apparently not show all CLR processes

Tags: .net, visual-studio, process

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff427522.aspx), the clrver.exe tool will show all processes on the computer that are using the CLR if you use

```
clrver -all
```

But when I run this it doesn't display a .Net application I've written. My app must be using the CLR to run, so it seems strange that it's not in the list.

Do you know why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is no doubt a version problem.  Type `where clrver.exe` to see which one you are using, it should show you one or two, stored in the Windows SDK directory.  When you get the one in `Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools` then you'll have a version that can detect processes that run CLR version 2 as well as CLR version 4.

However, when you get the one in `Bin`, or only have an old version of the SDK installed (6.0 or earlier) then you'll run a clrver.exe version that doesn't know anything about .NET 4 and up.  So you'll only see the processes that run CLR version 2.

You'll need a version checker for clrver.exe.  Bit ironic, isn't it ;)

Comment: Thanks Hans, I do indeed have two versions, and the one in `bin` only shows v2, and the one in `bin\NETFX..` shows v2 and v4 - but still neither of them are listing my application. Strange

Comment: I can't see your app from here, you'll have to describe it better.  Why is this a problem anyway?  What are you really trying to use this tool for?

Comment: Just knocked up a WPF application in C# and when it's running I expected `clrver -all` to include it in the list of processes using the CLR. I was using the tool to check the CLR version on a few machines and then I checked out the `-all` mode and thought it was odd that an app written in C# didn't show up.

Comment: I dunno, that doesn't help.  Post your problem to connect.microsoft.com, they'll need to be able to repro the problem to get them to pay attention.  So thoroughly document it, version numbers of build tools and a small repro project are essential.